# wp_redirect does not work

Tags: redirect

I have a problem with `wp_redirect` which does seem to redirect. It's a full url that is on the current website. I need to put `exit();` after `wp_redirect` for it to redirect. Is this normal? Redirect is in an `init` action btw.

Comment: Read first line under "Usage" https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing [`wp_redirect()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_redirect/) is adding HTTP header to the current request. It doesn't prevent request from proceeding to further loading page and **must** be followed by exit statement to work correctly.